# If cell value in worksheet 3 matches cell value in worksheet 2 AND specified cell in worksheet 2 contains given text replace with

Tags: vba, excel

If cell value in worksheet 3 matches cell value in worksheet 2 AND specified cell in worksheet 2 contains given text replace with either Disney DCL or Disney WDTC.

```
Sub changedisney()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet


Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws1 = wb.Sheets("April")
Set ws2 = wb.Sheets("alljobs")
Set ws3 = wb.Sheets("New")

x = ws3.Cells(ws3.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = x To 2 Step -1
        If ws3.Cells(i, 4) = ws2.Cells(i, 1) And ws2.Cells(i, 7) = "gtb*" Then
            ws3.Cells(i, 2) = "Disney DCL"
        End If
        If ws3.Cells(i, 4) = ws2.Cells(i, 1) And ws2.Cells(i, 7) = "wdtc*" Then
            ws3.Cells(i, 2) = "Disney WDTC"
        End If
Next i


Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Comment: Okay.  Is there an issue with the code?

Comment: It runs, but it doesn't do anything

Comment: One thing to try is change `ActiveWorkbook` to `ThisWorkbook`.

Comment: Check out how you're calling the loop - are you *sure* that `x` is going to be greater than 2?

Comment: You're checking to see if column D cells on sheet "New" match column A cells on sheet "alljobs" *in the same row*.  So it's not looking anything up, it's doing direct comparison row by row.  Is that supposed to be that way, or should it be looking up a match in "alljobs"?

Comment: @tigeravatar no it's not supposed to do that. Thanks for catching

Comment: is "gtb*" the correct way to specify field containing gtb? For example would it pick up gtb12345

Comment: `ws2.Cells(i, 7) LIKE "gtb*"`

Comment: An alternative can also be `LEFT(ws2.Cells(i, 7), 3) = "gtb"` and `LEFT(ws2.Cells(i, 7), 4) = "wdtc"`.